# Pandas dataframe, change columns name

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this code that creates a table with dates and predictions from a previous ML code

```
    gv = pd.date_range(str(d1), periods=15)
    lst_output = pd.DataFrame(lst_output)
    pred_log = lst_output.apply(np.square)
    pred = pred_log.apply(np.exp)
    dv = pred[0]
    gv = pd.DataFrame(gv)
    gv['Forecast'] = dv
    gv.to_csv('app/forecast.csv')

    return render_template('analyse.html', get_plot = True, data = data,tables=[gv.to_html(classes='data')], titles=gv.columns.values)
```

Now, the output looks like this

[image]

but I'd like to make it a bit better, like renaming the '0' in the 2nd column with 'Date' and removing the 'Forecast' on the left. And also, removing the first column with the bold numbers would be great!

Could you please help me out? Thanks!

EDIT:

I've managed to change the name of the second column:

```
    gv = gv.rename(columns={gv.columns[0]: 'Days'})
```

But still not sure how to remove the 'Forecast' on the left!

Also, this is the code to actually show the table in HTML:

```
      <div id="table">
        {% for table in tables %} {{titles[loop.index]}} {{ table|safe }}
      </div>
```

EDIT2:

So, with this code

```
    gv['Forecast'] = dv
    gv = gv.rename(columns={gv.columns[0]: 'Days'})
    gv.set_index('Days', inplace=True)
    gv.to_csv('app/forecast.csv')
```

I have this table:

[image]

While with this code:

```
    gv['Forecast'] = dv
    gv = gv.rename(columns={gv.columns[0]: 'Days', 'Forecast': ''})
    gv.set_index('Days', inplace=True)
    gv.to_csv('app/forecast.csv')
```

I have this table:

[image]

Comment: do you want to remove the whole column for the Forecast or just have an empty column name for it?

for an empty column name:

gv = gv.rename(columns={gv.columns[0]: 'Days', 'Forecast': ''})

Comment: For dropping the 0-14 index that you don't want - after the rename - 

gv.set_index('Days', inplace=True)

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
gv = pd.date_range(str(d1), periods=15)
lst_output = pd.DataFrame(lst_output)
pred_log = lst_output.apply(np.square)
pred = pred_log.apply(np.exp)
dv = pred[0]
gv = pd.DataFrame(gv)
gv['Forecast'] = dv

# new code is here:
# this, as you'd found, renames columns
gv.rename(columns={gv.columns[0]: 'Days', 'Forecast': ''})

# the bold column with 0-14 is the index, by setting 'Days' to index,
# you can drop that column - inplace=True just means you don't have 
# to store the returned value, and instead it modifies your "gv" dataframe
# directly
gv.set_index('Days', inplace=True)

gv.to_csv('app/forecast.csv')

return render_template('analyse.html', get_plot = True, data = data,tables=[gv.to_html(classes='data')], titles=gv.columns.values)
```

Comment: Hey Jmc, first of all thanks for your help!

I've edited the question so that I could add the screenshot of the table.. it's still a bit strange the output, what do you think? Thanks!